# Outlook 2013/2016 Add-In: Outlook.MailItem.Copy()-method doesn't work on a active inline response item

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I have a C# Outlook add-in, and on 2013 and 2016. There is a problem with the new functionality where you can reply to an email from the reading-pane.

However my add-in does some stuff which requires a copy of the MailItem. But the Copy-method gives an exception.

> "This method can't be used with an inline response mail item."

I have found little info about this, other than that is not supported.

Does anyone have ideas how to get around this? One link suggested opening it first with `.Display(false)`. However, this doesn't help. Same error is raised. `Display(true)` will open it in a new window and leave the old one open. The Send button won't work and it is stuck in a infinite loop somewhere. Not a working solution either.

Would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I never got any replies, but seems like Redemption can do this with copyto()-method.